# Add file in directory depending on the extension

Tags: php

In my server I have different directories, such as:

**/--js**,
**/--html**,
**/--php**,
**/--css.**
And I want to create method like this `addFile($file_name,$file_extension)`
And creating in my directory file like `$file_name` and in directory in `$file_extension` and this file will have extension like `$file extension`.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.file-put-contents.php). You can add data and create the file with any extension. In the $filename you can put the full path to the folder and filename.

Renember that file_put_contents does not create the directory structure. Only the file.

To prevent this you can use something like this:

```
if (!is_dir('upload/images/')) {
  // dir doesn't exist, make it
  mkdir('upload/images/');
}

$image = 'file.txt';
$some_data = 'Text inside your file';

file_put_contents('upload/images/' . $image, $some_data);
```

Otherwise you can learn about creating files from this article http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

So your method will be something like:

```
function addFile($file_name, $file_extension) {
  $dirs = ['js', 'css', 'html', 'php'];
  foreach($dirs as $dir) {
      if($dir == $file_extension) {
          file_put_contents($dir . '/' . $file_name . '.' . $file_extension, 'Some text data? ');
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rough example perhaps the following might be useful?

```
function addfile( $filename=false ){
    if( $filename && file_exists( $filename ) ){

        clearstatcache();

        $basedir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $ext=pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        $name=pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_BASENAME );

        switch( $ext ){
            case 'css': $dir='/css/'; break;
            case 'txt': $dir='/txt/'; break;

            case 'js': $dir='/js/';break;
            case 'html': $dir='/html/'; break;
            case 'php': $dir='/php/'; break;

            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg': $dir='/images/jpg/'; break;
            case 'png': $dir='/images/png/'; break;
            case 'gif': $dir='/images/gif/'; break;

            case 'mp3': $dir='/audio/mp3/'; break;
            case 'mp4': $dir='/video/mp4/'; break;

            default: $dir=false; break;
        }
        if( $dir ){
            $targetpath = $basedir . $dir;

            if( !file_exists( $targetpath ) ){
                /* create the directory - recursively if necessary */
                createdirs( $targetpath );
            }

            return file_put_contents( $targetpath . $name, '', FILE_TEXT );
        }

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}



function createdirs( $path=NULL, $perm=0644 ) {
    if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
        createdirs( dirname( $path ) );
        mkdir( $path, $perm, TRUE );
        clearstatcache();
    }
}
```